# Running total with in each group using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, cumulative-sum

I am trying to write a SQL to calculate running total with in each group in the below input. Just wondering how can I do it using MySQL. I am aware of how to do it in regular SQL using analytic functions but not in MySQL. Could you share your thoughts on how to implement it.

SQL Fiddle :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59366d/19

SQL using window function :

```
SELECT e.Id,
       SUM( e.Salary ) OVER( PARTITION BY e.Id ORDER BY e.Month  ) AS cumm_sal
  FROM Employee e 
LEFT JOIN
       (
          SELECT Id,MAX(Month) AS maxmonth
            FROM Employee
          GROUP BY Id
        ) emax
    ON e.Id = emax.Id
WHERE e.Month != emax.maxmonth
ORDER BY e.Id,e.Month DESC;
```

Input :

```
Create table Employee (Id int, Month int, Salary int);

insert into Employee (Id, Month, Salary) values ('1', '1', '20');
insert into Employee (Id, Month, Salary) values ('2', '1', '20');
insert into Employee (Id, Month, Salary) values ('1', '2', '30');
insert into Employee (Id, Month, Salary) values ('2', '2', '30');
insert into Employee (Id, Month, Salary) values ('3', '2', '40');
insert into Employee (Id, Month, Salary) values ('1', '3', '40');
insert into Employee (Id, Month, Salary) values ('3', '3', '60');
insert into Employee (Id, Month, Salary) values ('1', '4', '60');
insert into Employee (Id, Month, Salary) values ('3', '4', '70');
```

Output :

```
| Id | Month | Salary |
|----|-------|--------|
| 1  | 3     | 90     |
| 1  | 2     | 50     |
| 1  | 1     | 20     |
| 2  | 1     | 20     |
| 3  | 3     | 100    |
| 3  | 2     | 40     |
```

Comment: What about using window functions in MySQL? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

Comment: Its about solving it without using window functions.

Comment: What do you want to show running totals for? Months? Employees? Edit your question to show the expected output for the example output in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL, the most efficient approach is to use variables:

```
select e.*,
       (@s := if(@id = e.id, @s + salary,
                 if(@id := e.id, salary, salary)
                )
       ) as running_salary
from (select e.*
      from employee e
      order by e.id, e.month
     ) e cross join
     (select @id := -1, @s := 0) params;
```

You can also do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select e.*,
       (select sum(e2.salary)
        from employee e2
        where e2.id = e.id and e2.month <= e.month
       ) as running_salary
from employee e;
```

Comment: Please note the use of variables (first solution) will only work in MySQL (as far as I know), so it's not a standard solution that could work on other databases. On the flip side, the correlated subquery (second solution) is a standard solution; however, correlated subqueries are inherently slow, and will become slower the more rows you have. But I guess, that's the nature of your problem, and this could be the *best* solution.