# MySQL Running Total on multiple columns grouped by another column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create running totals on multiple columns based on grouping by another column.

Starting with the approach in the answer here [Running total with in each group using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570479/running-total-with-in-each-group-using-mysql) I can get it to work for totaling one column but any additional columns after that calculate a running grand total - the grouping is ignored.

Sample data - games table

```
|TeamID|GameID| w| l|
|------|------|--|--|
|     1|     1| 1| 0|
|     1|     2| 0| 1|
|     1|     3| 1| 0|
|     1|     9| 0| 1|
|     1|    10| 1| 0|
|     2|     4| 1| 0|
|     2|     5| 1| 0|
|     2|     6| 1| 0|
|     2|     7| 0| 1|
|     2|     8| 0| 1|
|     3|     1| 0| 1|
|     3|     2| 1| 0|
|     3|     3| 0| 1|
|     3|     7| 1| 0|
|     3|     8| 1| 0|
|     4|     4| 0| 1|
|     4|     5| 0| 1|
|     4|     6| 0| 1|
|     4|     9| 1| 0|
|     4|    10| 0| 1|
```

Desired result - cumulative w and l, grouped by TeamID

```
|TeamID|GameID| w| l|cum_w|cum_l|   Pct|
|------|------|--|--|-----|-----|------|
|     1|     1| 1| 0|    1|    0| 1.000|
|     1|     2| 0| 1|    1|    1|  .500|
|     1|     3| 1| 0|    2|    1|  .667|
|     1|     9| 0| 1|    2|    2|  .500|
|     1|    10| 1| 0|    3|    2|  .600|
|     2|     4| 1| 0|    1|    0| 1.000|
|     2|     5| 1| 0|    2|    0| 1.000|
|     2|     6| 1| 0|    3|    0| 1.000|
|     2|     7| 0| 1|    3|    1|  .750|
|     2|     8| 0| 1|    3|    2|  .600|
|     3|     1| 0| 1|    0|    1|  .000|
|     3|     2| 1| 0|    1|    1|  .500|
|     3|     3| 0| 1|    1|    2|  .333|
|     3|     7| 1| 0|    2|    2|  .500|
|     3|     8| 1| 0|    3|    2|  .600|
|     4|     4| 0| 1|    0|    1|  .000|
|     4|     5| 0| 1|    0|    2|  .000|
|     4|     6| 0| 1|    0|    3|  .000|
|     4|     9| 1| 0|    1|    3|  .250|
|     4|    10| 0| 1|    1|    4|  .200|
```

I modified the code in the link above and am running this... (I'm not even trying to calculate the Pct yet)

```
    select g.*,
       (@w := if(@TeamID = TeamID, @w + w, 
                 if(@TeamID := TeamID, w, w)
                )
       ) as cum_w, 
       (@l := if(@TeamID = TeamID, @l + l,
                 if(@TeamID := TeamID, l, l)
                )
       ) as cum_l        
from (select TeamID, GameID, w, l
      from games) g
cross join (select @TeamID := -1, @w := 0, @l := 0) params
order by TeamID, GameID;
```

What I get. Cumulative w works, Cumulative l is a running grand total which ignores the TeamID. If I remove cum_w, cum_l works. If I reverse the order in the select statement the first one works and the second one doesn't

```
|TeamID|GameID| w| l|cum_w|cum_l|
|------|------|--|--|-----|-----|
|     1|     1| 1| 0|    1|    0|
|     1|     2| 0| 1|    1|    1|
|     1|     3| 1| 0|    2|    1|
|     1|     9| 0| 1|    2|    2|
|     1|    10| 1| 0|    3|    2|
|     2|     4| 1| 0|    1|    2|
|     2|     5| 1| 0|    2|    2|
|     2|     6| 1| 0|    3|    2|
|     2|     7| 0| 1|    3|    3|
|     2|     8| 0| 1|    3|    4|
|     3|     1| 0| 1|    0|    5|
|     3|     2| 1| 0|    1|    5|
|     3|     3| 0| 1|    1|    6|
|     3|     7| 1| 0|    2|    6|
|     3|     8| 1| 0|    3|    6|
|     4|     4| 0| 1|    0|    7|
|     4|     5| 0| 1|    0|    8|
|     4|     6| 0| 1|    0|    9|
|     4|     9| 1| 0|    1|    9|
|     4|    10| 0| 1|    1|   10|
```

Ultimately, I will have two more columns which have running totals grouped by TeamID, plus running 10 game w & l and pct within that 10 games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user defined variable gets overwritten in the first column. Add a second one for lost

> ```
> CREATE TABLE games (
>   `TeamID` INTEGER,
>   `GameID` INTEGER,
>   `w` INTEGER,
>   `l` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO games
>   (`TeamID`, `GameID`, `w`, `l`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '1', '0'),
>   ('1', '2', '0', '1'),
>   ('1', '3', '1', '0'),
>   ('1', '9', '0', '1'),
>   ('1', '10', '1', '0'),
>   ('2', '4', '1', '0'),
>   ('2', '5', '1', '0'),
>   ('2', '6', '1', '0'),
>   ('2', '7', '0', '1'),
>   ('2', '8', '0', '1'),
>   ('3', '1', '0', '1'),
>   ('3', '2', '1', '0'),
>   ('3', '3', '0', '1'),
>   ('3', '7', '1', '0'),
>   ('3', '8', '1', '0'),
>   ('4', '4', '0', '1'),
>   ('4', '5', '0', '1'),
>   ('4', '6', '0', '1'),
>   ('4', '9', '1', '0'),
>   ('4', '10', '0', '1');
> ```

> ```
>     select g.*,
>        (@w := if(@TeamID = TeamID, @w + w, 
>                  if(@TeamID := TeamID, w,w)
>                 )
>        ) as cum_w, 
>        (@l := if(@Team2ID = TeamID, @l + l,
>                  if(@Team2ID := TeamID, l, l)
>                 )
>        ) as cum_l        
> from (select TeamID, GameID, w, l
>       from games order by TeamID, GameID) g
> cross join (select @TeamID := -1, @Team2ID := -1, @w := 0, @l := 0) params
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> TeamID | GameID |  w |  l | cum_w | cum_l
> -----: | -----: | -: | -: | ----: | ----:
>      1 |      1 |  1 |  0 |     1 |     0
>      1 |      2 |  0 |  1 |     1 |     1
>      1 |      3 |  1 |  0 |     2 |     1
>      1 |      9 |  0 |  1 |     2 |     2
>      1 |     10 |  1 |  0 |     3 |     2
>      2 |      4 |  1 |  0 |     1 |     0
>      2 |      5 |  1 |  0 |     2 |     0
>      2 |      6 |  1 |  0 |     3 |     0
>      2 |      7 |  0 |  1 |     3 |     1
>      2 |      8 |  0 |  1 |     3 |     2
>      3 |      1 |  0 |  1 |     0 |     1
>      3 |      2 |  1 |  0 |     1 |     1
>      3 |      3 |  0 |  1 |     1 |     2
>      3 |      7 |  1 |  0 |     2 |     2
>      3 |      8 |  1 |  0 |     3 |     2
>      4 |      4 |  0 |  1 |     0 |     1
>      4 |      5 |  0 |  1 |     0 |     2
>      4 |      6 |  0 |  1 |     0 |     3
>      4 |      9 |  1 |  0 |     1 |     3
>      4 |     10 |  0 |  1 |     1 |     4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=651f2caf3ffe3c615d71200894b58281)*

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick.

I knew it was something simple, yet somehow I was completely baffled last night.